# Changing the selected marker Google Maps iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I have multiple markers in my google map. Each containing different information.  When the user click on the marker a small view appears containing all the information. I have put up a swipe gesture on the view. What i want to achieve is that when user swipes from left to right the next marker appears in the center of the map.

**

> I just need to know some logic or example. what should i implement on
>   swipe handler that changes the marker.

**
*Gracias*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the swipe from left to right gesture might interfere (both programmatically as from a user's point of view) with the normal behaviour of this gesture on a map - scrolling it.

That said, you'll have to keep an NS(Mutable)Array of markers somewhere (there is no property on `GMSMapView` which gives you all markers). Upon detecting the gesture, find the index of the [`mapView.selectedMarker`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view.html#a13d41c8eafc158f95bd7e4d0b052c8f5) in the array, retrieve the next one and update `mapView.selectedMarker`. The map might automatically scroll to the marker, but if not, you can do this with [`setCamera:`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/views#moving_the_camera).